# Xampp / Composer / Zend Framework 2 Installation issues

Tags: php, xampp, zend-framework2, composer-php

Ok, so I have a composer.json file, a composer.lock file, and a composer.phar file. All the info I need to install Zend Framework I believe is in the .json file, however I have no idea what I'm doing with composer, and have no idea how to use the .phar file. If someone out there can help me out, I would be super great-full. I've been reading tutorials, and watching videos but I'm fairly new to the technical side of php. I've never worked with libraries, or command prompts, so this is all WAY over head.

Comment: I suggest [my Tutorial on how to install ZF2 on Xampp](http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start:

http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Step one: Download composer.phar

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Step Two:

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

That will download all the file dependencies outlined in the composer.json file.

A couple notes:

- Above assumes you are using a bash prompt (Linux or cygwin on windows) If your not using linux you can download composer.phar from getcomposer.org.
- You have php in your system path meaning that when you type php in your command line it will run the php executable/binary.

Comment: I keep getting an error "'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file."

Comment: Ignore the $, that was meant to indicate that the command should be entered at a command prompt